# Read bytes from PROGMEM array

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, memory-usage, memory, progmem

**Disclaimer:** I just started using C++ and I'm a bit of a beginner. Keep that in mind as your answering.

So I recently bought my first Arduino. It's a customized one and it has an 8x8 display attached to it. To display something on the display, the company I bought it from recommends storing the instructions for the display in a two-dimensional byte array.

I now have a longer animation I want it to play, so I researched and found [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) which lets me store much more data. So I write something along the lines of:

```c
const byte frames[2][8] PROGMEM {
  {
    B10000100,
    B10000100,
    B10000100,
    B10000100,
    B10000100,
    B10000100,
    B10000100,
    B10000100,
  },
  {
    B10010100,
    B10010100,
    B10010100,
    B10010100,
    B10010100,
    B10010100,
    B10010100,
    B10010100,
  }
};

void setup() {
  arduino.begin();
}

void loop() {
  arduino.printImage(frames[0]);
  delay(1000);
  arduino.printImage(frames[1]);
  delay(1000);
}
```

After compiling, it throws a few errors at me:

```c
warning: invalid conversion from 'const byte* {aka const unsigned char*}' to 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
   arduino.printImage(frames[0]);
                      ~~~~~~~~^
```

This did not worry me as much and I just ignored those. After uploading, however, the display just showed arbitrary patterns instead of the lines I told it to draw.

After I removed the PROGMEM, it worked flawlessly, however, the memory wasn't big enough to store the array (not the one I provided as an example).

I could think of two reasons:

1. In the [official documentation of PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/), it states that you have to get the variables back into memory. However, none of the methods they provided worked for me.
2. In a [similar question on ASE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63178/read-nested-array-item-from-progmem), both answer and comments state that nested arrays aren't supported, but my knowledge of C++ isn't good enough to understand the answer.

Comment: @Juraj It's downloadable through the IDE. It's called Gamer.h.

Comment: @Juraj In the "Arrays of strings" it tells me to do something like this: `strcpy_P(buffer, (char *)pgm_read_word(&(frames[1])));
  arduino.printImage(buffer);`
However, it just tells me that `'buffer' was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 2):

On [the question you are referencing](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63178), the accepted answer suggests
to modify the library. This could be the most efficient option. A less
invasive solution, however, would be to copy the data from the flash
memory to RAM, and use the `printImage()` function as is.

Obviously, copying everything to RAM defeats the purpose of PROGMEM. But
you only need to copy one frame at a time, and only hold it in memory
for little more than the duration of the call to `printImage()`:

```cpp
void printProgmemFrame(const byte flashFrame[8]) {
  byte ramFrame[8];
  memcpy_P(ramFrame, flashFrame, 8);
  arduino.printImage(ramFrame);
}

void loop() {
  printProgmemFrame(frames[0]);
  delay(1000);
  printProgmemFrame(frames[1]);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it sadly still just displays arbitrary patterns. Do I need to do anything else except for inserting your `printProgmemFrame`-function and replacing the `loop` function?

Comment: @gurkensaas: In principle you need nothing else. I cannot test this, as I do not have the hardware. It works for me, however, with a mock of the `arduino` object.

Comment: The code compiles fine, it uploads fine, but the problems of the arbitrary patterns stay the same.

Comment: I think you are returning `ramFrame` which is allocated on the stack when you call `printProgmemFrame`. Try again adding `static` to the variable declaration:

`static byte ramFrame[8];`

Comment: @EugenioPace It generated another random pattern.

Comment: Shouldn't there be something extra in the declaration of printProgmemFrame()? Something like `void printProgmemFrame(const byte flashFrame[8] PROGMEM)`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Alas, no. Unlike the [`__flash` keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html#AVR-Named-Address-Spaces-1), which works like a type qualifier (like `volatile` or `const`), `PROGMEM` is really only a kludge to get the compiler allocate the variable in a specific program section. This works only when the variable is actually declared: it makes no sense for a pointer to be declared as “pointer to PROGMEM data”. It's a pity `__flash` is only supported in C mode (not in C++).